# PHP OR statement issue when validating file extension

Tags: php

I have an issue when using PHP OR statements to validate the extension of the uploaded file. The below code should check the file extension and define an error if it does not equal PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF.

This is my code:

```
$file_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if($file_extension !== "png" || "jpg" || "jpeg" || "gif") {
    $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF';
}
```

However it will only work if I define just one file extension, for example:

```
if($file_extension !== "png") {
    $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG';
}
```

This will accept PNG files and refuse any others.

What do I need to do to get this code to work as intended?

Comment: You need to setup an array and check if it is `in_array()`.

Comment: Just read some php basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
if(!($file_extension == "png" || $file_extension == "jpg" || $file_extension == "jpeg" || $file_extension == "gif")) {
    $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF';
}
```

Solution 2:

```
if($file_extension !== "png" && $file_extension !== "jpg" && $file_extension !== "jpeg" && $file_extension !== "gif")) {
    $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF';
}
```

Solution 3:

```
$ext = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
if(!in_array($file_extension, $ext)) {
    $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF';
}
```

---

Solution one is based on the negation of alternatives. This is the same as solution two (which is the sum of negated). These two solutions are equal in sense of logic, but...

**Solution 3** is of course better. That is because, each time in the future You will need to check the extension, the array of extensions will be available to You. And writing everytime, the same if with the same "constants" is wrong, and future improvements are difficult.

---

In that case, try to declare array of possible extensions at the beginning of your script, in your config class, or in CONSTANTS (left it to you), and every time you need to check the file extensions, just check the in_array. And in the future, if you need additional extensions, or decide that for example gif is not useful anymore, just change this one array. Every other line of code should stay as it is.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use the OR operator as you want to. You could do something like this:

```
$file_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(!in_array($file_extension, array("png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"))) {
    $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF';
}
```

For more information about `in_array()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Technically the first answer by 2 seconds. (with an explanation) as to why the OP's code failed from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for you

First Solution :

```
<?php
    $file_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if($file_extension !== "png" || 
    $file_extension !== "jpg" || 
    $file_extension !== "jpeg" || 
    $file_extension !== "gif") {
        $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF';
    }
?>
```

Second Solution :

```
<?php
    $file_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if(!in_array($file_extension, array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif'))) {
        $error = 'Thumbnail file must be a PNG, JPG, JPEG or GIF';
    }
?>
```